# Why there are multiple storage motors in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server, myisam

Why there are multiple storage motors in MySQL?
If Make compare between MySQL and MSSQL with storage motor property. Which DBMS have advantage?

Comment: It is called a Storage Engine, not a motor ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you meant 'Storage Engines' instead of 'Storage Motors'

basically different engine is meant for different purpose, some are meant to handle transactions, some are meant for fast reads. I shall refer you to [Storage Engines on MySQL Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/storage-engines.html)

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion MySQL and MsSQL are two different levels of databasesystems. And which one you pick depends on the situation (linux, windows) and what your requirements are. MsSQL is more grown up in my opinion and MySQL is very easy to use with webapplications.

There is a lot to find on the internet.